# Docebo Api Integration

Tags: api, authentication

I am facing an issue with implementing the API to authorize the user and make a session and launch a course.

All the full steps like making a token and passing it with REST API has been done and in the response I am receiving the success in the response token.

Now the issue is that when I am trying opening a course link, it redirects me to the login page despite landing on course. Can you please help set up a session and let me know which API is to be used to make a session so that it doesn't redirects me to the login page.

Comment: Can we see some relevant code?  It is very hard for us to envision your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Will add the code soon

Answer (score 3):

For those still looking for an answer, I'll show you how to generate a temporary link that will authorize a user and direct them to the desired location in Docebo.

Things you need:

- The **username**.
- The **SSO secret** for the token hash.

  -In Docebo: Click APPS and Features on left-hand side. Click Third party integrations. Activate API and SSO, if not already activated. After API and SSO is active, click on its gear icon. Click the check box that starts with "Enable SSO with...". Enter a SSO secret in the box below the checkbox. Save.

Now, for the implementation. I myself used C# for this but hopefully it will be easily translatable to your language of choice (or lack of choice).

**The basic idea is this:**

1) Create an MD5 hash of three values: 
(NOTE: Include commas between the values when generating the hash. Example further below...)

- **username**(lowercase!!!)
- **time** = Seconds since the Unix Epoch in utc.
- **SSO secret** (the one you typed yourself).

2) Get the hex value of the hash.

3) Combine the destination url with the username, time, and hex. Like so:

**http[s]://[yourdomain]/lms/index.php?r=site/sso&login_user=[username]&time=[utc
time]&token=[token]{&id_course=[id_course]}{&destination=[destination]}**

For my example, I didn't specify a course or a destination.

Here is the above gibberish, in C#:

```
    public string GenerateDoceboSSOLink()
    {
        string userName = "johnsmith"; //Note the lowercase!!
        string domain = "http://my-test.docebosaas.com";
        string ssoSecret = "MySSOSecret";

        //Getting the seconds since the Unix Epoch
        TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        int time = (int)t.TotalSeconds;

        //Creating the hash...
        MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
        //Note the inclusion of the commas!
        string input = userName + "," + time + "," + ssoSecret;
        byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        //Getting the hex value of the hash. 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }

        string token = sb.ToString(); //the hex value, which we will call token

        //The sso link. 
        string link = String.Format("{0}/lms/index.php?r=site/sso&login_user={1}&time={2}&token={3}", domain, userName, time, token); 
        return link;    
    }
```

So, I followed [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByFTWHNMAC1JYjdpOGVITjRRbG8) 
impossible-to-find documentation that led me to what you see above (I couldn't find the  url so I just shared it).